# New line does not display when getting jira issue using php soap

Tags: php, soap, jira

I am trying to get issue details from JIRA 3.13 using PHP SOAP. I was able to login and get the issues; however, on one of my field, I could not get the new line formatting. So, all I got is the text for that particular field without new line character (everything just append into a single line of text). As of now, I am guessing php also did some re-formatting of the string from SOAP. The reason I am saying this is because I did some testing with SOAP UI and was able to get the text out with the formatting. Can anyone help me out with a way to displaying the text with the formatting? Thanks in advance.

This is my php code:

```
try {
    $soap   = new SoapClient("<<JIRA URL>>");
    $auth   = $soap->login($formUsername, $formPassword);

    if ($auth)
    {

        $result0 = $soap->getIssue($auth,'<<JIRA ISSUE ID>>');

        $result = (array) $result0;

        foreach ($result as $key => $a)
        {
            $z = $z . '<br/>' . $key . ' = ' . $a;
        }

        echo $z;
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $string = urlencode($e->getMessage());
    header("Location: login.php?message=".$string);
    die();
}
```

---

I just realize that I do not need to convert it into array.
Simply do the following:

```
    foreach ($result0 as $key => $a)
    {
        $z = $z . '<br/>' . $key . ' = ' . $a;
    }
```

This, however, still does not solve my problem with the new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just because you don't change the linefeeds into `<br/>` before outputting it?

Should be easy to find out if that's the case just by looking at the source in the browser.

Comment: I tested the output by passing it into htmlspecialchars(..) and getting a result without new line formatting. However, If instead I pass __getLastResponse for the soap into htmlspecialchars(..), then I can see the new line formatting.

Comment: I don't think htmlspecialchars transforms lf to <br/>. It is used to transform characters into html entities, not tags.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that my <br/> tag in the post was interpreted a bit too litteral by so :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert newline characters (`\n` et. al) into HTML `<br>` tags:

```
foreach ($result0 as $key => $a)
{
    $z = $z . '<br/>' . $key . ' = ' . nl2br($a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the text is stored with Unix line endings and you're displaying on a Windows machine? Which field is having the problem?

Comment: the description field. I don't think this is related to windows and linux formatting.